# All applications timeout when single, high-throughout operation running

Tags: networking, router, internet, tcp

My internet connection has a decent speed of about 15 megabits/s. However, whenever there is a high-throughout operation running (e.g. file download, dropbox sync..), this occupies the full bandwidth and all other applications (e.g. browsing, pinging) start to timeout. I tried bypassing my access point, and wiring straight to the ISP hub, but nothing. The same computer on another connection works fine. This seems like the ISP's fault, but what exactly?

I studied telecommunications engineering, but I am bit rusty on my TCP-IP. All I can remember is that when multiple TCP sessions are competing, the one with lower round-trip-time (RTT) typically gets an unfair share of bandwidth. But TCP is the same all over, so what could the ISP (or me?) be doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like an extreme case of an all-too-common router bug called “bufferbloat”.